# convert a data frame column imported from excel to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a column of hundreds of names that I imported from excel spreadsheet looking like this:

```
list1 <- read.xlsx("path",1)

list1

     name
1    apple
2    banana
3    cat
4    dog
5    egg
6    frog
....
```

I was told that when you import an excel file to R, the excel table information is imported as `data.frame`.  I would like to convert this data frame into a list like the following when I input "

```
> list1" :
apple, banana, cat, dog, egg, frog....
```

Since I have hundreds of names (not necessarily in alphabetical order), I need to find a way to automatically do this function instead of myself inputting it as a list one after one.

Comment: I don't think this is *really* what you want. What is your goal?

Comment: If you're reading a lot of files or excel sheets, you could try the `l/apply` function to do it in one go. You can work on entire lists using `lapply`. If that's indeed your goal, try searching `[r] list.files do.call lapply` in the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NewList <- as.list(list1$name)
```

Basically, all you need to to do is coerce the column you want to change to a list with the as.list() function.